# How does topology on a space relate to differentiation?

Tags: general-topology, manifolds, differential-topology

I read in Chapter 1 of Lee's *Introduction to Smooth Manifolds* that

> there's no way to define a purely topological property that would serve as a criterion for smoothness.

So, I tried to think about the meaning of this sentence and I couldn't really link topology to differentiation! I mean derivatives of functions are defined on open domains, and openness is a topological abstract concept. But how are the two related? I mean assume that I change the topology of the real line from the Euclidean metric to some other topology. For example, discrete topology or the topology generated by half-open intervals $[a,b)$. How will the notion of differentiation change then?

I assume we have to study functions defined on $\mathbb{R}$ to answer this. So, some examples of functions that are differentiable with respect to the Euclidean topology but fail to be differentiable in some other topology or vice versa are appreciated.

Comment: Write down  the definition of derivative and convert the impression into purely metric space language. I hope this will lead you to where you want to go.

Comment: @JackyChong: Metric space language is hardly purely topological.

Comment: @tomasz Even in metric space language the notion of a derivative is not well defined (or at the very least not easily defined). I don't see the point of talking about derivative say for instance for the discrete topology.

Comment: @JackyChong: Fair enough, but I think I vaguely recall some rudimentary derivative-like notions for (fairly?) general metric spaces, whereas I can't imagine one that would work in general topological context, for lack of any quantitative tools.

Comment: @tomasz The one I know about for metric space is far from rudimentary https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wasserstein_metric. This gives us a notion of gradient flows on metric spaces. In general, even in metric space things are highly nontrivial and very close to current research.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As far as I can guess what Lee might have meant, on the basic level, the reason is that smoothness properties are not preserved by homeomorphisms, and hence smoothness of a function is not a topological property.

There is no need to go into exotic topologies (where it doesn't a priori make sense to talk about smoothness${}^\dagger$). For example, the identity function on the real line is certainly smooth, but if you compose it with a non-smooth homeomorphism of the line (say, a piecewise linear strictly increasing function), you will get a non-smooth function.

On a somewhat deeper level, you can have two differential manifolds which are homeomorphic, but have incompatible differential structures, such as regular and [exotic spheres](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exotic_sphere).

($\dagger$ There are more robust notions of smoothness and manifolds than those of real manifolds. For example, given any [local field](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Local_field) (like the $p$-adics), you can pretty much rewrite the standard definitions of smoothness and a manifold and they work just fine. But I am not aware of any such notion which would work for the lower limit topology.)

Comment: +1 for writing exactly what I would have said, and more.

Comment: This is an excellent explication of what I had in mind. Thank you!

Comment: @JackLee: Thank you as well. It is very nice to get such a compliment from the author himself!

Comment: Thanks, Tomasz. Lee explains right in the next sentence what he means by that sentence and he gives the exact same explanation as yours. But I had this particular example in mind: Consider the graph of $y=|x|$ as a curve. It can be covered by a single chart projecting $(x,|x|)$ to $x$ and therefore, it's a manifold. Now extend this chart to a maximal smooth atlas. This gives us, theoretically, a smooth manifold with a new topology on it which differs from the Euclidean topology. Right? I still don't see how one can do "calculus" with this manifold!

Comment: @user375190: It does give us a manifold, but there is no new topology. It is the same (topologically and differentially) as the real line, so this is just a convoluted way of writing the same thing. This should come as no surprise: all you did was pull back the differential structure of the real line via a homeomorphism! If you do that, you get (by definition) something diffeomorphic to the original manifold, so you can't really do anything interesting with that.

Comment: I'm confused. Isn't $(x,|x|)$ non-differentiable in the Euclidean sense (by considering the subspace topology inherited from $\mathbb{R}^2$)? Isn't the manifold I defined differentiable?

Comment: @user375190: But I have just told you that the topology does not tell you about differentiability. The graph is a smooth manifold if you equip it with the differential structure pulled back via the projection, however, it is *not* a submanifold of ${\bf R}^2$, because it has a corner at $(0,0)$. Similarly, you could pull back the metric from the real line onto the graph and that would be a decent metric space, but it would not be a metric subspace of ${\bf R}^2$ with standard metric. (Although in this case the graph can be made into a metric subspace of ${\bf R}^2$, with a different metric.)

Comment: @user375190: More extremely, you can take an insane (say, Bernstein) subset of real line of cardinality of the continuum, fix a bijection with the real line and pull back the topology from the line. Topologically, that would be the same as the original line, but that would be very distinct from the subspace topology. The difference in the differential case is that there may be *no* way to inherit the manifold structure to just any set (not without making concessions on the definition of a manifold, anyway).

Comment: Now I see. Thanks for the explanations.